# angular 7 routing to same component but different param not working

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have 2 router outlets: sidebar and the default one.

```
 {path: 'motor/:id', component: MotorComponent}
```

From the sidebar outlet i have some router links to the default router outlet that target the same component (MotorComponent) but different param.

```
this.router.navigate(['./', {outlets: {primary: ['motor', 
id]}}]);
```

If i click on one, the respective component is loaded but if i click on another router link the correct component is not loaded. The param changes in the url.

I read it is a common problem. I tried with a reuse strategy but i don't think it was well implemented, nothing happened.

I would like to click on different router links that target the same component but different params and the component would load even if it is the same component.

This is my ngOninit where i subscribe to route params, save that id and then fetch my new object from the service.

```
motor: MotoarePrincipale;
id: number;

ngOnInit() {
this.route.params.subscribe(
  (params: Params) => {
    this.id = +params['id'];
  }
);
this.masinaService.getMotorByMotorId(this.id).subscribe(data => {
  this.motor = data;
});
```

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to route params in the ngOnInit funtion()
`this.route.params.subscribe(params => ....)` ?

Comment: Yes, i am already subscribing to route.params.subscribe because i save that id. I need that id to fetch from my service the new object. What are you referring to?

Comment: could you provide a little more code to elaborate on? maybe your ngOnInit or constructor, whichever defines and holds your observables and subscriptions

Comment: I added my ngOnInit!

Comment: check Robert 's answer as he's got it explained well there. Basically you need to make your motor object an observable `motor$: Observable<MotoarePrincipale>;` and second you need to ` | async` in your template. Try to work it out from here.

Comment: i will analyze it. for the moment i managed to set my motor object after i subscribe to the route params and fetch the motor object from my service, as you suggested. The object changes and this is what i want for the moment.

Answer (score 15):

for angular 7(I tried only on this version) you could use in your component the route reuse strategy:

```js
constructor(private routerR: Router) {

    // this is for routerLink on same component when only queryParameter changes
    this.routerR.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
      return false;
    };
  }
```

Comment: Can confirm that this works in Angular version 10.2 for me

Comment: Works in Angular 12 as well. Tysm you saved my day.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had 200+ lines of `onInit()` code and the variables in there don't reset to their default values unless the entire component reloads. And I don't want to introduce a bug by forgetting to reset every single value in the `onInit()` at the beginning of `onInit()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
private route: ActivatedRoute,
private router: Router
```

You need to listen for id changes in your url, and finally to switch map to correct id. Look at this example from [RXJS Observables in Angular - Ward Bell & Sander Ellis](https://youtu.be/q--U25yPTrA?t=1525)

Here an implementation example, where you can see movies based on their id without refreshing the page:

TS:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Movie } from '../../samples/sw-interfaces';
import { FilmService } from './film.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  template: `
      <h1>Routed Movie Component</h1>

      <div>
        <button (click)="previousMovie()">Previous</button>

        <div *ngIf="currentMovie$ | async as movie; else noMovie"  class="title">
            ({{movie.id}}) {{ movie.title }}
        </div>

        <ng-template #noMovie>
            <div class="missing">No Movie</div>
        </ng-template>

        <button (click)="nextMovie()">Next</button>
      </div>
    `,
  providers: [FilmService],
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  currentMovie$: Observable<Movie>;

  currentId: number;
  nextId: number;
  previousId: number;

  routerEventsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(
    private filmService: FilmService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listenToRouteParams();
    this.listenToRouterEvents();
  }

  private listenToRouteParams() {
    // ActivatedRoute.paramMap observable changes whenever the URL's id changes
    this.currentMovie$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(

      // extract film id parameter
      map(params => params.get('id')),

      // switchMap because can discard in-flight request for a new id
      switchMap(id => {
        return this.filmService.getFilm(id).pipe(
          tap(movie => this.currentId = movie ? movie.id : 0)
        );
      })
    );
  }

  nextMovie() {
    this.navigate(this.currentId + 1);
  }

  previousMovie() {
    this.navigate(this.currentId - 1);
  }

  navigate(id: number) {
    id = id || 1;
    this.router.navigate([`/movie/${id}`]);
  }




  /// ROUTER EVENTS ////
  private listenToRouterEvents() {
    // Listen to the router do its thing
    // What is `routerEventsSubscription`?
    this.routerEventsSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('Router event: ', event);
    });
    console.log('MovieComponent initialized');
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('MovieComponent destroyed');

    // Question: Why must we unsubscribe from the router?
    // Question: Why do we NOT unsubscribe from `route.paramMap`
    this.routerEventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

SERVICE:

```
// tslint:disable:member-ordering
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Movie, RootObject } from './../sw-interfaces';
import { SwUrlService } from '../../samples/sw-url.service';

@Injectable()
export class FilmService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private swUrlService: SwUrlService) {}

    getFilm(id: string) {
      return this.http.get<RootObject<Movie>>(`${this.url}/${id}`)
        .pipe(
          map(data => data.results),
          catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 404) {
              return of(undefined); // OK if not found.
            }

            // log HTTP error and ...
            console.error('GET failed', err)
            // rethrow as a user-friendly message
            throw new Error('Sorry but can\'t get movies right now; please try ain  later');
          })
        );
    }

    private get url() {
        return this.swUrlService.url;
    }
}
```